# How can I decode a h.264 / MP4 byte array into a bitmap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-streaming, skiasharp

In Xamarin.Forms, I send a TCP request to a server and get an MJPEG byte stream back. I put each frame data into a byte[] array. I then use SkiaSharp.SkBitmap.Decode(byte[] buffer) to return a bitmap, which I then paint on an SKCanvas.

```
using (var canvas = surface.Canvas)
            using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(imgBytes))
            using (var paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    canvas.DrawColor(SKColors.Black);
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, info.Rect, paint);
                }
            }
```

In the same fashion, how could I decode a h.264 byte[] array (frame data) into a bitmap?

Comment: Hi, this will need two steps. One is need a decoder to decode the h.264 stream data, then you will get the video byte[] data. Second , you can convert the byte[] data to bitmap .You can use ffmpeg to decode h.264 stream file.You can use install **Xabe.FFmpeg** Nuget Package, and there is a way can [change video to images by ExtractEveryNthFrame](https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/docs.html). However, if want project has higher efficiency, you can deal with that in native.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'm currently trying to use RtspClientSharp to decode the frame bytes I am getting. If that doesn't work I will try Xabe.FFmpeg! Either way I will try to post a working answer. Thank you

Comment: RtspClientSharp will decode stream into h264 frames. If you want to decode rtsp into bitmap, you can use libvlcsharp.